# Laravel livewire not getting data (DateRangePicker)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm using laravel and livewire and I'm trying to pass over the date range's date to my function. The issue I'm having
is that I'm getting an empty string.

I'm also using https://www.daterangepicker.com/#example1 for my daterange.

Here is my code.

My index.blade.php

```
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="dateTest">
        <input type="text" wire:model="date_range" id="testDateRange"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit date</button>
    </form>
</div>

@push('js')
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#testDateRange').daterangepicker({
                opens: 'left'
            }, function(start, end, label) {
                console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

and this is my Index.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Products;

use Livewire\Component;

class Index extends Component
{
    public $date_range = '';

    public function dateTest()
    {
        dd($this->date_range);
    }
}
```

*** UPDATE ***
I had to change the the date picker to be this one https://www.daterangepicker.com/#example4  so here is my new code

```
        <form wire:submit.prevent="dateTest">
            <input type="text" id="startDateTest" onchange="this.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input'))" wire:model="date_range" class="form-input block w-full sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">

            <div id="reportrange"  style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%" wire:model="startDate">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
                <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Submit date</button>
        </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var start = moment();
        var end = moment();

        function cb(start, end) {
            $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        }

        $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
            startDate: start,
            endDate: end,
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            }
        }, function(start, end){
            $('#startDateTest').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

            cb(start, end);
        });

    });
```

Comment: Could you try adding `onchange="this.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input'))"` to your input and see if it works.

Comment: @Remul - I tried your suggestion and it worked for my first one, but then I had to change my date picker and I tried your suggestion again, but it didn't work with this one.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use @this.set method to set livewire variable.

this is an example for dateTimePicker i hope you will understand how to implement it in dateRangePicker.

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
   <input wire:model.lazy="startDate" type="text" id="startTime"  class="form-control" name="startDate" readonly>
</div>

<script>
        $('#startTime').datetimepicker({
            format: 'd-m-Y H:i',
            step: 5,
            minDate:0,
            onChangeDateTime: function (dp,$input) {
                @this.set('startDate', $input.val());
            },
        });

        $('#endTime').datetimepicker({
            format: 'd-m-Y H:i',
            step: 5,
            onChangeDateTime: function (dp,$input) {
                @this.set('endDate', $input.val());
            },
        });
 </script>
```

in livewire component class get variables like :

```html
$finalEndDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i',$this->endDate);
$finalStartDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i',$this->startDate);
```